# Facebook v2.4 with OAuth2 stopped working and only getting name and id

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, owin

Something changed from facebook APIs v2.3 to v2.4 - after using 2.4 I can only get name and id,

I saw some posts talking about adding a "?fields=scopes..." but it's a true mystery for me - I'm trying to understand how to send these scope fields...

Here is my code:

```
        var facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();

        facebookAuthOptions.AppId = facebookAuthAppId;
        facebookAuthOptions.AppSecret = facebookAuthAppSecret;

        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("public_profile");

        facebookAuthOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
        {
            OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
            {
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966530/asp-net-mvc-5-1-c-sharp-owin-facebook-authentication-or-login-ask-for-birthday/25967936#25967936
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                foreach (var claim in context.User)
                {
                    var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                    var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                    if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1: I tried to inject the scope fields like this:

```
facebookAuthOptions.UserInformationEndpoint += "?fields=email,user_birthday,first_name,last_name";
```

But still not working...

UPDATE 2: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714500/access-email-address-in-the-oauth-externallogincallback-from-facebook-v2-4-api-i/31715332#31715332) that makes it possible to get the email, but I have to install additional [Facebook SDK for .NET](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk) which I prefer to avoid... also found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999934/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-problems-getting-user-email/8013211#8013211) that shows how to extract more values like birthday (in facebook APIs v4.3 I had to send birthday and not user_birthday)
dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me?fields=email,birthday");
I'm still looking for a way to send the scope values through the standard Oauth2 methods...

UPDATE 3:
I managed to get more info using the Facebook .NET SDK - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933544/3187389
But still prefer not be able to do that with the standard Oauth2 (and Owin) without using Facebook .NET SDK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! finally... and working with the new facebook APIs v2.4

So maybe I can save someone else 6 hours :-)

You will need to install Facebook SDK for .NET

This is how I fixed it:

```js
// Use Facebook SDK for .NET to get more specific data (https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk)

var identity = AuthenticationManager.GetExternalIdentity(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var facebookAccessToken = identity.FindFirstValue("FacebookAccessToken");
var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookAccessToken);

dynamic facebookInfo = fb.Get("/me?appsecret_proof=YourFacebookAppSecretProof&fields=email,birthday,gender");
signInInfo.Email = facebookInfo.email;
```

**UPDATE:** it is now also required to pass in the appsecret_proof (added to the snippet)

Comment: Hi, you can do it anywhere, I put it in my account controller inside the method that handles to new signup with an external provider.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook made some changes in 2.4. You only get those two fields by default now, if you want any other fields you have to explicitly request them:

> Declarative Fields
>   To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for your GET requests. For example, GET /v2.4/me/feed no longer includes likes and comments by default, but GET /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes will return the data. For more details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to translate that for the Library that you're using.

Comment: Hi. I'm using the latest version 3.0.1 of the default Microsoft.Owin.Security (Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook), if I have to use a custom SDK then it defeats the purpose of using Oauth2 - I'm very interested in finding a solution for this...

Comment: I think your idea of injecting the scopes is along the right lines. Ultimately you'll be making a GET request, and they are just appended as querystring variables. I think it's going to depend on the exact value of that UserInformationEndpoint string though. If that string already has a "?" then you might need to just append with a leading "&"

Comment: @Yovav, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059384/why-new-fb-api-2-4-returns-null-email-on-mvc-5-with-identity-and-oauth-2). It's an 100% OAuth solution.